# cPickle class with data save to file

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, object-persistence

I've big class in Python it's "DataBase-like" class. I want to save it to file - all including data.

This is input(example to show the issue, in script database is like 10000 records):

```
import cPickle
# DataBase-like class
class DataBase:
    class Arrays: pass
    class Zones: pass
    class Nodes: 
        class CR: pass    
    class Links: 
        class CR: pass
    class Turns:
        class CR: pass    
    class OrigConnectors: pass
    class DestConnectors: pass    
    class Paths: pass
    pass
# some basic input into database
DataBase.Arrays.Data=[]
for i in range(1000):
    DataBase.Arrays.Data.append([i+4]) 

print DataBase.Arrays.Data[56]

# and now I want to save it to file

import cPickle    

filename='D:/results/file.lft'
file=open(filename,'w')
cPickle.dump(DataBase, file, protocol=2)`
```

And that's the file I get:

```
€c__main__
DataBase
q.`
```

There's no data, just definition. How can I overcome that. Maybe saving my data as a class is not a good idea?

Comment: You should read up on how Python's classes work: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 4):

You are pickling "DataBase" which is a class definition.  You need to instantiate an object of class DataBase then pickle that.

```
objDataBase = DataBase()
objDataBase.Arrays.Data = etc....

filename='D:/results/file.lft'
file=open(filename,'w')
cPickle.dump(objDataBase, file, protocol=2)
file.close()
```